# Choose top n variables in R when matching values

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a large timeseries dataset, and would like to choose the top 10 observations from each date based one the values in one of my columns.

I am able to do this using *group_by(Date) %>% top_n(10)*

However, if the values for the 10th and 11th observation are equal, then they are both picked, so that I get 11 observations instead of 10.

Do anyone know what i can do to make sure that only 10 observations are chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `arrange` the data and select first 10 rows in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(Date, desc(col_name)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% slice(1:10)
```

Similarly, with `filter`

```
df %>% 
 arrange(Date, desc(col_name)) %>% 
 group_by(Date) %>% 
 filter(row_number() <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` you can do

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[order(Date, desc(value))][, .SD[1:10], by = Date]
```

Change `value` to match the variable name used to choose which observation should be kept in case of ties. You can also do:

```r
df[order(Date, desc(value))][, head(.SD,10), by = Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
df1 <- df[with(df, order(Date, -value)),]
df1[with(df1, ave(seq_along(Date), Date, FUN = function(x) x %in% 1:10)),]
```